# Regexp - optional dot in a decimal number

Tags: regex

I've written two Regexp's that allow for the following formats:

- X
- X.
- X.Y

Where Y can be 1 or 2 digits. And X is unlimited.

Regex1: `^\d+(?:\.{0,1})(?:\d{1,2})?$`

Regex2: `^\d+\.{0,1}(?:\d{1,2})?$`

Is one better than the other?

Is there a better way to write this?

Also, why doesn't this one work where the dot is just set as optional: `^\d+(?:\.)(?:\d{1,2})?$`

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `^\d+(?:\.)(?:\d{1,2})?$` doesn't work is that it does *not* make the . optional as you say.  the `(?:` ... `)` is not how you make something optional; its main use is grouping multiple things together (so that a subsequent `?`, '+', etc. could modify the group) without producing a capture value.

Make something optional by following it with a `?`.  So:

```
^\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?$
```

should work.  It's simpler - so imo preferable - to either of the other options you showed.  Simpler still:

```
^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$
```

ought to be fine.

Comment: @fractal5 \d will allow 0001 for instance, so you may want to use: `^([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9].?\d{0,2}` (or something similar)

Comment: @fractal5 - Perhaps you intended this as a comment on the question?  Because as a comment on my answer - since my answer is based on the requirements spelled out in the question, which don't state that leading 0's should be excluded - it's incorrect.

Comment: Got it. Yeah I just realized that the ? after the ) is what makes it optional. Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger It's just a comment for the OP taking into account your improvement of his regex. It looks more relevant to me to keep them together. Your answer is perfect accordingly to the requirements ! Keep cool :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better way to write this?

You can use this regex without any groups:

```
^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/1)

`\d{0,2}` allows for absence of any digits after period. Also note that `\.{0,1}` is same as `\.?`

Comment: @fractal5 \d will allow 0001 for instance, so you may want to use: `^([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9].?\d{0,2}` (or something similar)